# Which song was played in Naruto Shippuden episode 378 at about 20:00?

Tags: naruto, music

Which song was played in Naruto Shippuden episode 378 at about 20:00?

I can't find the song. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no song around 20:00 in the episode. at that time minato's kunai was broken and he lost his one hand. however if you are referring to the ending song then it is **"Never Change feat.Lyu:Lyu"** (around 21:00)